# Web scraping Yahoo financial data via a list of tickers

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, yahoo, yahoo-finance

I am trying to scrape yahoo finance for the summary financial table. Instead of doing it one by one I was hoping to do it by a list or a csv file.

Currently I am able to scrape multiple tables but when I try and used df.read_html it only gives me one table.

Does anyone know a better way of doing this? so far my code is:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open('ticker_list_test.csv') as f:
    for ticker in map(str.strip,f):
        url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}".format(ticker)
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
        yahoo_table = soup.find_all("table", "W(100%)")
        print(yahoo_table)
df = pd.read_html(str(yahoo_table))
```

My ticker_list_test.cvs is just 3 ticker symbols - AAPL, SPY and NFLX.

thanks

Comment: with open('ticker_list_test.csv','r') as f: